# requests.get does not return all the information on the web page

Tags: python, web-scraping, request

I'm trying to use webscraping (python) to download a video from a website.
As you can see on the following capture, I can see the div I want to select.

[image]

But when I try to extract this content with BeautifulSoup, I get an empty result.

BeautifulSoup is not the problem, the problem is that `response.text` (see the following code) does not contain this section (however the divs surrounding this div are present in the response).

```
import requests                
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.jw.org/nsi/library/bible/nwt/books/genesis/1"

response = requests.get(url) 
if response.status_code != 404 :
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")          
    print(soup.select("div[class^='video-js']"))
```

Comment: There is no “all this information” in the html, as your image of the content shows, so it’s not a problem with BeautifulSoup or requests.get, is it. Chances are the video reference is loaded by some javascript on the page. You should probably use a browser simulator like Selenium which will run the javascript.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. If you know how to do this, please show me. I'm on google colab.